# Auto-focus to pop-up after clicking a link

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible to automatically focus to the pop-up (be it a modal window or a dialog box) after clicking a link.

I found something like this from [How can selenium web driver get to know when the new window has opened and then resume its execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9188343/how-can-selenium-web-driver-get-to-know-when-the-new-window-has-opened-and-then#answer-9191759)

```
driver.find_element_by_id("id of the button that opens new window").click()        
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=50).until(found_window("new window name"))
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=10).until( # wait until the button is available
    lambda x: x.find_element_by_id("id of button present on newly opened window"))\
    .click()
```

But even here we need to know the id or any attribute of the pop-up. Is there some way we can run an automated script in Selenium so that it catches any pop-up window and auto-focus to that and returns back to the parent window only once the tests are performed on the pop-up.

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I use Selenium-Python

Answer (score 0):

```
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
```

for accept it

```
alert.accept()
```

Have a look here:

[How to test Alert/Popup in Selenium using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37866584/how-to-test-alert-popup-in-selenium-using-python)

[Check if any alert exists using selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python)

Comment: @Carlo 1585 Thanks for your response.But doesn't this go only for alert boxes? To clarify - By 'pop-up' I meant any window that would pop-up other than alert boxes. That is why I didn't mention alert box but other pop-up dialog box or modal windows.

Comment: Hi guys, yes it should work only for alert but if you try it in the real life scenario it will work even for pop-up; I used it with python 2.7 and for me worked without problems! I even interact with a window to browse on your desktop and upload an image, after I got other problem with the same page but doing the switch_to_alert I could move to the pop-up. Give it a try ;)

Comment: @Carlo 1585 My requirement is that if such a case is possible, I need to fetch all the links present in the pop-up. But with the following command I didn't find a way. Could you please help me here.

Comment: I think you can find what you are searching for in this 2 post (I add them to my answer)